# Blocking Lawbringer's Impaling Charge

Tags: for-honor

Is there any way to block Lawbringer's Impaling Charge move? I know a possible way to negate this is to dodge left or right but I'm looking for a way to *parry*, *block* or *counter* this charging attack.

Perhaps only certain characters can do this?

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @peilonrayz I mean block in the same way as it's used throughout the game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested it with a friend and you basically have 4 options if you see a Lawbringer running towards you:

**Dodging**
As you've mentioned it's possible and super easy to dodge the charge. This is probably the safest method that also allows you to reposition yourself.

**Blocking**
Also rather easy since the attack always comes from left. However this offers no big benefits unless you want to stay where you are. You might be able to follow up with a guard break though.

**Parrying**
Definitely the most powerful option of the four. If you parry the charge the Lawbringer will lose about 75% of his stamina and he will be staggered. It's also not too hard since the attack will always come from the left. The only tricky part is the parrying itself but the timing isn't too tight.

**Attack interrupt**
This is by far the most difficult one of the four and can only be done by high range characters since the lawbringer himself has a very high range. It is possible to stagger the him out of the charge with a light or heavy attack. While there's a huge potential if you use a heavy attack, the timing usually is extremely tight and if you want to use it you should definitely practice against a friend first. Most of the time you're better off dodging/parrying though if you want to land an attack after a charge.

Comment: As an addendum to dodging, for some classes this opens up the fight in their favor. With the berserker you can dodge into a light attack, and use it to start your chain. This puts you behind and to the left (if you dodge to the right, which you should vs this attack) of your opponent, giving you a few seconds of free reign.

Answer (score 1):

Block to your left, the impaling charge after he's running always is an attack from the left. If he parries you and then does an impaling charge, simply block in the direction its coming from.

Comment: I see you edited from right to left. Can anyone confirm the validity of this answer? Either way I'll try it out when I'm home and I'll report back.

Comment: I main Lawbringer with some playtime and always when i run my attack comes only from one side. I just flipped it because for me the person holds the weapon on the right side.